# Apps missing from Usage Access menu?

Tags: accessibility

I installed Avast Anti-theft on to my Moto X running Resurrection Remix on Marshmallow, and I'm having a strange issue with the accessibility settings. Apps are missing from the usage page. When I search the page for the app, it just isn't there. Is there a way I can manually grant usage without using the settings menu? I'm rooted.

In the app...
[image]

And in the accessibility page...
[image]

Comment: See if you can detect shortcut to this activity using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut). You can then place that on desktop as a widget to trigger without going through settings

Comment: @beeshyams take a look at the images I attached. I think you're  misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Indeed this is different.